# MongoDB: Arrays as PK

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

I have keys that looks like this: 34834.3245.94.5134 - it is string obviously.
But I can split it and store as array of integers [34834,3245,94,5134]

1) is this array more efficient to store, index and search?

2) is it possible to create index with {unique:true} on that key?

Comment: Your title mentions `PK`, are you intending to use this field as your `_id` value?  You can't use an array for `_id`.

Comment: How are you planning to search the array?  For example: always using the full key; using partial keys (if so, what part(s)?); using range comparisons ?  Range comparisons and sorting behave differently on strings and integers so "efficiency" depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, in the case of sufficiently long numbers, you should get more compact indexes in memory, but much more elements in index(it will slow queries).
2. Yes, but keep in mind this rule

   > If you use the unique constraint on a compound index then MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the combination of values, rather than the individual value for any or all values of the key.